# How do I edit a key pair in a document in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-test

I want to edit the following key pair in Cloud Firestore:
[image]

For this I created a button that calls the following function:

```
void select(key) {
    if (key == 'Stufe 1') {
      stufenService.editStufe('Stufe', 1);
    }
    if (key == 'Stufe 2') {
      stufenService.editStufe('Stufe', 2);
    }
    if (key == 'Stufe 3') {
      stufenService.editStufe('Stufe', 3);
    }
    if (key == 'Stufe 4') {
      stufenService.editStufe('Stufe', 4);
    }
    if (key == 'Stufe 5') {
      stufenService.editStufe('Stufe', 5);
    }
    if (key == 'Stufe 6') {
      stufenService.editStufe('Stufe', 6);
    } print(key);
  }
```

This is the exact code of stufenService.editStufe(String, int):

```
final CollectionReference userTodos =

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userTodos');
  
  Future editStufe(String Stufe, int i) async{
    return await userTodos.doc(userID).update({Stufe: i});
  }
}
```

When I press the button that calls ’select', only the key is printed in the console.
Nothing changes in Cloud Firestore.
I think the mistake is somewhere here:

```
final CollectionReference userTodos =

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userTodos');

  Future editStufe(String Stufe, int i) async{
    return await userTodos.doc(userID).update({Stufe: i});
  }
}
```

I hope I have provided all the necessary data so that the problem can be solved. If not, just write it to me and I will try to send you the material you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reviewing google and external documentation, you could use the following code example to update your key pair on `Cloud Firestore`:

This is an example code of how to update your key pair using ‘`update`’:

```
const usuariosRef = db.collection(‘userTodos’);

//userTodosRef.doc(‘ID’)

userTodosRef
    .doc(‘81Acc0wgLegYMSTTrCWLRQhzjA2’)
    .update({
          stufe = 1
    });


This is an example code of how to update your key pair using ‘`set`’:

const usuariosRef = db.collection(‘userTodos’);

//userTodosRef.doc(‘ID’)

userTodosRef
    .doc(‘81Acc0wgLegYMSTTrCWLRQhzjA2’)
    .set({
          stufe = 1
    });
```

The difference between both is that ‘update’ only changes the value you want to update, ‘set’ deletes all the data and updates it with the value added.

Here is a document that could help you with references you can performed with your data: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#update

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just don’t understand part of your explanation: `const usuariosRef = db.collection(‘userTodos’);` You no longer use usuarioRef. And should I use: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userTodos');` instead? db isn't initialiezed in my code.

Comment: In addition, `stufe = 1` is underlined in red. Error: `The argument type 'Set<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, Object?>'. `

Comment: Calling **set** with an ID that already exists on the collection will replace all the document data. You can also specify **SetOption(merge: true))** on the query, and will merge the existing document with the data passed into the set( )

`CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> addUser() {
  return users
    // existing document in 'users' collection: "ABC123"
    .doc('ABC123')
    .set({
      'full_name': "Mary Jane",
      'age': 18
      },
      SetOptions(merge: true),`

Comment: If you'd like to update a document instead, use the **update** method

`CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> updateUser() {
  return users
    .doc('ABC123')
    .update({'company': 'Stokes and Sons'})
    .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));
}`

Set and update are examples, you can edited with your code
Remember to update the .doc ID with the ID: 81Acc0wgLegYMSTTrCWLRQhzjA2

Comment: It looks like it’s working at first glance. I create the following future in 'StufenService': `Future<void> updateUser(String text, int i){
    return users
        .doc('8lAcc0wgLegYMST5TrCWLRQhzjA2')
        .update({text : i})
        .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));}` And for the function of the button, I used this code: `void select(key){
    if (key == 'Stufe 1') {
      stufenService.updateUser('Stufe', 1);
    }` The console also prints User Updated. But the document in firebase remains at ’Stufe':0